# ASP button even not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have set up a page with a submit button that the user can click and log in. I need to gather the field values and then do some backend stuff, but when the button is clicked, the even handler method I have set up doesn't fire. Heres the button code:

```
<asp:Button UseSubmitBehavior="false" CssClass="btn btn-primary" ID="btnTest" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnTest_Click" />
```

And the codebehind:

```
public partial class SignIn : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnTest.Click += new EventHandler(this.btnTest_Click);
    }

    protected void btnTest_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string user = username.Value;
        string pass = password.Value;
        int userid = -1;
        RoomSvc.Data.Person[] persons = RoomService.Service.ServiceClient.GetPersons();
        RoomSvc.Data.Person pUser = null;
        foreach (RoomSvc.Data.Person p in persons)
        {
            if (p.username == user && p.password == pass)
            {
                pUser = RoomService.Service.ServiceClient.GetPerson(userid.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }
        }
        RoomService.Global.currentUser = pUser;
    }
}
```

I have tried everything out there and nothing is making it work, could someone please enlighten.

EDIT: .aspx code:

```
    <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="SignIn.aspx.cs" Inherits="RoomService.Account.SignIn" %>



   <asp:Content ID="SignInHeader" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    </asp:Content>
    <asp:Content ID="SignInContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
        <form action="SignIn.aspx" class="form-horizontal well span5 offset5">
            <fieldset>
              <legend>Sign In</legend>
              <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="input01">Username</label>
                <div class="controls">
                  <input runat="server" type="text" class="input-medium" id="username" />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="input01">Password</label>
                <div class="controls">
                  <input runat="server" type="text" class="input-medium" id="password" />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-actions">
                <asp:Button CssClass="btn btn-primary" ID="btnTest" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnTest_Click" />
              </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </asp:Content>
```

Comment: Is your button living inside <form ...> </form>

Comment: Is this an asp web application of web site? Is this code in an aspx page? Did you try to remove the UseSubmitBehavior="false"?

Comment: Have you tried removing UseSubmitBehavior="false"?

Comment: yea, when that is removed, then Page_Load gets called when I click submit, which is fine, but it still wont fire the click event. Also this is an asp web app

Comment: Please show us your complete .aspx code

Comment: You added `OnClick` event twice, in the `aspx` and codebehind. You should use one

Comment: i have tried removing both (one at a time) and it still doesnt work, the btnTest_Click is still never entered.

Comment: Looking at your aspx code, a content page should not have a `form` tag, that should be in the MasterPage. Is there any reason you are doing things differently

Comment: @Matt, based on the comments under Hats answer, can you confirm whether or not there are nested `<form>` tags? I don't just mean in the content page, but in the final rendered HTML

Comment: it was, that was my mistake, its been corrected now, i have removed the one from the content, but the event still does not fire.

Comment: Check your masterPage there should be a form tag there. Remove the one on this page and try to click the button and see what happens

Comment: how did you test the event was not fired. Put a break point in the event

Comment: I cant, it complains that it is needed for a navigationmenu

Comment: yes, i have a breakpoint to test the event.

Comment: If you are browsing the page through IIS the breakpoint won't work. Will only work if you press F5/Debug in the Visual Studio

Comment: i know that, i am running it from visual studio, I have a breakpoint in Page_Load() and it enters that just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

I had to add the even handler in Page_Init() not Page_Load()

Answer (score 1):

Your form tag is missing runat="server

Comment: @MattGrogan sorry I should have read the comments below you question before posting my answer

Comment: adding that gives me an exception: System.Web.HttpException: A page can have only one server-side Form tag.

Comment: @MattGrogan the error means you have 2 form pls can you take ruant="server" on the other form try again and check if it is hitting the break point inside btnTest_Click(

Comment: but I don't have 2 forms, i have posted the entire aspx page above

Comment: correction, i do have 2 forms, one is in the site.master, so i removed the on from sign in which is ok. But the event still does not fire.

Comment: @MattGrogan so u removed runat from the form in master but did you tried it after adding it back to the other form

Comment: yeah, i tried, it complains that runat="server" is needed for the navigation menu.